# Longtable package leads my table to become too wide

Tags: tables, longtable, width

I am new to LaTeX. I have been trying to create a literature review table using longtable. Without the longtable package my table is the right width, however when I do decide to use the longtable package, my table becomes far too wide for the page.
Could anyone guide me and tell me what I need to do solo this?

```
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}

    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Authors}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Study/sample details}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Childhood SEP}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Physical capability}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Covariates}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Association}} \\ \hline
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \endhead
    %
    (Birnie et al., 2011) &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Study: Systematic review \\ \\ Date: Inception to 2010 \\ \\ Sample size:Grip strength (N = 1,061,855)\\ \\ Walking speed (N = 20,770)\\ \\ Chair rise (N = 17,215)\\ \\ Standing balance (N = 22,156)\\ \\ Age at outcome: 18-79 years\end{tabular} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1) Father’s occupation \\ 2) Father’s education\\ 3) Mother’s education\\ 4) Childhood economic environment \\ \\ 9/11 studies had retrospective\\ ascertained\end{tabular} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Grip strength \\ Walking speed\\ Chair rise speed\\ One-leg Standing balance\end{tabular} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Confounders\\ 1) Age\\ 2) Adult SEP\\ 3) Body size\end{tabular} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Model 1 (Confounder: 1)\\ Low childhood SEP = Poorer grip strength\\ Low childhood SEP = Reduced walking speed \\ Low childhood SEP = Reduced chair rise speed\\ Low childhood SEP = Poorer balance \\ \\ Model 2 (Confounder: 1-2)\\ Low childhood SEP = No association with grip strength\\ Low childhood SEP = Reduced walking speed \\ Low childhood SEP = Reduced chair rise speed\\ Low childhood SEP = No association with standing balance \\ \\ Model 3 (Confounder: 1-3)\\ Low childhood SEP = No association with grip strength\\ Low childhood SEP = No association with walking speed\\ Low childhood SEP = Reduced chair rise speed\\ Low childhood SEP = No association with standing balance\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    (Strand et al., 2011) &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Study: MRC NSHD\\ \\ Design: Birth cohort\\  \\ Setting: Britain\\  \\ Period: 1946-ongoing\\ \\ Sample size: n = 2,988\\ \\ Age: 53\end{tabular} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Mothers education (P) - ME\\ Fathers occupation (P) - FO\end{tabular} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Chair rise speed\\ Grip strength\\ Standing balance\end{tabular} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1) Childhood growth and home environment:\\ - Birth weight\\ - Height and weight\\ - Childhood growth\\ - Material home conditions, 4 yrs\\  \\ 2) Childhood cognition and coordination:\\ - Age at first walking\\ - Cognitive ability, 8 yrs\\ - Motor coordination, 15 yrs\\  \\ 3) Adult factors 53 yrs:\\ - Physical activity\\ - Height and weight\\ - Smoking\\ - Cognitive function\\ - Lung function (FEV1) - Health status\end{tabular} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Mode 0 (Adj: gender)\\ Low ME = No association with grip strength\\ Low ME = No association with chair rise speed\\ Low ME = Poorer standing balance\\  \\ Low FO = No association with grip strength\\ Low FO = Reduced chair rise speed\\ Low FO = Poorer standing balance\\  \\ Mode 1 (Adj: gender, height, weight)\\ Low ME = No association with grip strength\\ Low ME = No association with chair rise speed\\ Low ME = Poorer standing balance\\  \\ Low FO = No association with grip strength\\ Low FO = Reduced chair rise speed\\ Low FO = Poorer standing balance\\  \\ Mode 2 (Model 1 + CSEP)\\ Low ME = No association with grip strength\\ Low ME = No association with chair rise speed\\ Low ME = Poorer standing balance\\  \\ Low FO = No association with grip strength\\ Low FO = Reduced chair rise speed\\ Low FO = No association with standing balance\\  \\ Mode 3 (Model 2 + Childhood growth and home environment)\\ Low ME = No association with grip strength\\ Low ME = No association with chair rise speed\\ Low ME = Poorer standing balance\\  \\ Low FO = No association with grip strength\\ Low FO = Reduced chair rise speed\\ Low FO = No association with standing balance\\  \\ Mode 4 (Model 3 + Childhood cognition and coordination)\\ Low ME = No association with grip strength\\ Low ME = No association with chair rise speed\\ Low ME = Poorer standing balance\\  \\ Low FO = No association with grip strength\\ Low FO = Reduced chair rise speed\\ Low FO = No association with standing balance\\  \\ Mode 5 (Model 4 + Education and adult SEP)\\ Low ME = No association with grip strength\\ Low ME = No association with chair rise speed\\ Low ME = Poorer standing balance\\  \\ Low FO = No association with grip strength\\ Low FO = Reduced chair rise speed\\ Low FO = No association with standing balance\\  \\ Mode 6 (Model 5 + Adult lifestyle, health and cognition)\\ Low ME = No association with grip strength\\ Low ME = No association with chair rise speed\\ Low ME = Poorer standing balance\\  \\ Low FO = No association with grip strength\\ Low FO = Reduced chair rise speed\\ Low FO = No association with standing balance\\  \\  \\ Mode 7 (Fully adjusted)\\ Low ME = No association with grip strength\\ Low ME = No association with chair rise speed\\ Low ME = Poorer standing balance\\  \\ Low FO = No association with grip strength\\ Low FO = No association with grip strength\\ Low FO = No association with standing balance\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    (Starr and Deary, 2011) &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Study: Lothian birth cohort\\  \\ Setting: Scotland\\  \\ Period: 1921 -\\  \\ Sample size: n = 559\\  \\ Age: 79 - 87 years\end{tabular} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Participant’s education (P)\\ Father’s education (P)\\ Mother’s education (P)\\ Participant’s social class (P)\end{tabular} &
      Grip strength &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Wave\\ Vital status\\ Sex\\ Height\\ Weight\\ Participant’s adult SEP\end{tabular} &
      Low childhood SEP = poorer grip strength \\ \hline
    (Hurst et al., 2013) &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Study: MRC NSHD\\  \\ Design: Birth cohort\\  \\ Setting: Britain\\  \\ Period: 1946-ongoing\\  \\ Sample size: n = 2,229 \\ \\ Age: 60 -64 years\end{tabular} &
      Fathers occupation (P) - FO &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Chair rise speed\\ Grip strength\\ Standing balance\\ Timed up and go test (TUG)\end{tabular} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Adult height\\ childhood cognitive development\\ BMI\\ Lifetime smoking status\\ Adult occupation\\ Adult education\end{tabular} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Adjust all for gender\\  \\ Model 1: \\ Low childhood SEP = Poorer grip strength \\ Low childhood SEP= Reduced chair rise speed\\ Low childhood SEP= Poorer balance\\ Low childhood SEP = Slower TUG\\  \\ Model 1: Adjusted\\ Low childhood SEP = Poorer grip strength \\ Low childhood SEP = Reduced chair rise speed\\ Low childhood SEP = Poorer balance\\ Low childhood SEP = Slower TUG\end{tabular} \\ \hline
     &
       &
       &
      One-leg Standing balance &
      3) Body size &
       \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}
```

My table without the use of longtable package:

[image]

My table after the use longtable package:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ, the main font size that's in use, and how wide the page block is.

Comment: Have you tried using `longtabu` from the `tabu` package? You can define its width to `\textwidth` by starting the environment with `\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {*{6}{|l}|}`

Comment: Your second 'row' of the table (with (Strand et al., 2011) ) is so tall that it doesn't fit on the same page as the first row. In the last column(Association)  it has 71 sub-rows. You should find another kind of formatting where you split these up.
And it looks like the non-longtable example uses a smaller font.

Comment: longtable does not change the formatting of the table cells, but you have not provided a usable example (so we dont for example know the page size) and have not shown the non-longtable version at all

Comment: @shekura tabu is largely broken and has been abandoned by its author so is unsupported.

Comment: @Mico @David Carlisle, I am using LaTeX through Rmarkdown to create the above document. My preamble looks like the following

`---
title: "test2"
date: "23/02/2021"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
fontsize: 10pt
documentclass: article
geometry: margin = 0.8in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{lscape}
- \usepackage{longtable}
`


@Pieter van Oostrum Even after splitting the said row, documents, the issue persists.

Comment: Your table contains that much text, that I seriously doubt, you will ever be able to fit it into the textwidth while still keeping an at least somewhat readable font size. Probably it yould be beter to split the table or to chose an entirely different format, such as (nested) lists to present this kid of information.